# What happens if you edit a file during compilation?

Tags: java, scala, compilation

Sometimes compilation takes a long time, and I want to mess around with a file while it's compiling.  Will saving the new file during compilation affect the build?  Or is everything preloaded?

Comment: I tried it in scala using maven and it seems everything is preloaded.  I was wondering, is this the case with all compilers and languages?

Comment: Have you ever tried to rename Word document while it's open on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a meaningful question: "is this the case with all compilers and languages?"

It's more meaningful to ask, For a given build system, can I edit source during a build?

With an ant build, it's clear that ant decides early (based on file timestamps) what to compile, but you don't know exactly when the compile task is started.

It's surely true that the compiler reads the source file just once, but you don't normally know when that happens.

The interesting use case is:

When I run `sbt> ~ test`, will sbt complete a test run while I'm editing code, or will it stop midstream to recompile?

I could see that it's useful to have a command option to determine whether edits abort a test run.  You might want to see the test result, or maybe you're only interested in test results after a modification.

That's especially true if compile-and-test cycles seem interminable.

[Here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html) is the doc for testing.  The [doc for triggered execution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Triggered-Execution.html) says:

> Monitoring is terminated when enter is pressed.

which could be construed to mean that monitoring is not suspended while the task executes.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this my self and i see that everything is preloaded.You could add and edit about what you get also.

Comment: Which language/compiler did you use?  Do you think this is a one-off result for just your language/compiler combination or do all compilers preload the code?