# Can we modify a file during compilation?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, compilation, ninja

Similar to this question for java: [What happens if you edit a file during compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705782/what-happens-if-you-edit-a-file-during-compilation), I want to ask what would be the impact of modifying a file during C++ program compilation.

The program is using GCC for compilation. The helping tools for program building is `cmake` and `ninja`.

I always get an urge to change something in a file and then I remind myself the program is already building, so wanted to clarify it.

So, in conclusion,

1. Whether there is going to be an impact or not?
2. Some lights on underlying things happening behind the scenes during compilation?

Comment: What will happen is [an acute case of demons flying out of your nose](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons).

Comment: I would say, depending when you modify the file. you modify before any usage, all is fine; when reading file, probably a opening/saving file error, and for after, a recompilation would be needed to take into account your modification. And the worst, between usages: you might have ODR violation, so ill formad program NDR; potentially broken dependency "time".

Comment: On Visual Studio Community you can modify files in your project but you can't save the file if it is being compiled at the point you press save.

Comment: The compiler will not create a temporary snapshot of all files and libraries being compiled if that's what you are wondering. What actually happens will depend on the change / usage order as @Jarod42 described.